# Setting existing struct value in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to have a function for setting values inside an existing struct?
I'm talking about the idea of passing the existing struct into a function and setting that structs "name" value (for example)?

What I have:

**main.exs**

```elixir
  Code.require_file("user.exs") # Requiring in module

  person1 = User.constructor("Name") # Making a new user

  IO.write inspect person1
```

**user.exs**

```elixir
defmodule User do
  defstruct [name: ""]

  def constructor(name) do
    %User{name: name}
  end
end
```

Any way to get this idea working?

```elixir
def setName(struct, newName) do
  struct.name = newName
end
```

Thanks

Comment: When you initialize the struct, you should be able to just write it out like you did in your `user.exs` like `person1 = %User{name: "Name"}` instead of calling some constructor function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Absolutely. There are several ways this can be accomplished.

```elixir
  defmodule User do
    defstruct name: nil

    # Method 1
    def set_name(user, name) do
      %{user | name: name}
    end

    # Method 2
    def set_name(user, name) do
      user |> struct(%{name: name})
    end

    # Method 3
    def set_name(user, name) do
      user |> Map.put(:name, name)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Note that structs as all Elixir data structures are immutable, so all these actually create a new Struct with all fields having the same values as the old one except for name which is set to the new value.

Comment: Thank you. Im coming from OOP stuff so its a bit hard to get used functional stuff. Appreciated.

Comment: Also be aware that all of the approaches have subtle differences, especially when setting invalid keys. Method 1 will raise when trying to set a non-existing key (since a struct has all keys it will fail for invalid keys), method 2 will silently discard all invalid keys, method 3 will just set the value and potentially leave you with an invalid struct. So, please don't use `Map.put`! Finally, another possible method is `Map.update!`, which is equivalent to method 1.

Comment: @molnarpw remember that you can accept an answer if it helped you.